# Есть ли плагины для запись звука в браузерах мобильных устройств?

Tags: javascript, аудио, запись, web-audio, webapi

Подскажите есть ли удобные решения для записи звука \ голоса с браузеров мобильных устройств? Большинство библиотек, которые можно найти в сети, получили последние обновления до 2017 года. И сейчас они "торомозят" в мобильных браузерах или работают со сбоями.

Есть ли современные библиотеки или что-то еще для записи голоса напрямую с браузера?

Comment: Можно постараться написать самому используя - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia.
Библиотеки все стары как мир, тут согласен)

Comment: Сейчас начиная где-то с 6 версии андроида кодинг, связанный со звуком одинаков для компа и андроида, т. е., всё, что работает на компьютере, также фунциклирит и на андроиде. Мне попадалась библиотека, которая работает и там и там - recorder.js. Сейчас уже не помню, по какой ссылке я скачивал, возможно это что-то из этого: [AudioRecorder](https://github.com/cwilso/AudioRecorder) или [recorder.js](https://github.com/jwagener-soundcloud/recorder.js)

Answer (score 0):

Именно для мобильных телефонов я нашел для себя немного другой способ записи звука. Можно через инпут=file добавить capture и в телефоне, после нажатия на загрузку, откроектся приложение, типа диктофона, где пользователь запишет звук и сможет сразу загрузить файл на сайт. Пример инпута:

```
<input type="file" id="capture" accept="audio/*" capture />
```

Более подробно об этом можно посмотреть на видео:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dbrez37HlJM&list=LLFcbFGnqCwH3MMXoGAKHvVQ&index=2&t=0s

Comment: Дополню, что это не лучшее решение, просто подошедшее мне на данный момент.

Comment: Попробовал. В хроме открывается диктофон, после останова записи пишет сохранено, но я не нашёл, где. В UC-браузере отображаются 3 кнопки - запись, изображения, файлы, но запись означает сделать фото и сохраняется на телефоне.